# How can we give custom adapter for Material Exposed Dropdown?

Tags: java, android

I tried to give custom array Adapter in Material Exposed dropdown with image and text value. DropDown is shown perfectly but when I click on those dropdown item, the selected item value is set to something like @71232. And when I set it manually like this, Second time onwards the dropdown doesn't show up.

```
autocompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(...
...
@Override
public void onItemClick{
   setText(clickedItem.getText());
}
```

```
CustomArrayAdapter customArrayAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getContext(), list);
autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(customArrayAdapter);
```

This is my CustomArrayAdapter

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomArrayAdapter.AdapterItem> {

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context,
                                ArrayList<AdapterItem> itemList) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_dropdown, R.id.tv_text, itemList);
    }

    
    private View initView(int position, View convertView,
                          ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_dropdown, parent, false);
        }

        TextView tvText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
        ImageView ivImage = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
        AdapterItem currentItem = getItem(position);

        if (currentItem != null) {
            tvText.setText(currentItem.text);
            ivImage.setImageDrawable(getContext().getDrawable(currentItem.image));

        }
        return convertView;
    }

   
}
```

Comment: Implement getDropDownView override method